# Python: Fill out edges of binary array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm using the following code to generate an array based on coordinates of edges:

```
verts = np.array(list(itertools.product((0,2), (0,2))))
arr = np.zeros((5, 5))
arr[tuple(verts.T)] = 1
plt.imshow(arr)
```

which gives me

[image: array]

or, as a numeric array:

```
[[1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

Now, I would like to fill out the spaces in between the corners (ie. yellow squares):

[image: filledout]

so that I get the following array:

```
[[1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

Comment: Why not directly copying np.ones() on  arr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `(0,2)` using `range(0,3)` (`3` as ranges are inclusive-exclusive) that is

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
verts = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(0,3), range(0,3))))
arr = np.zeros((5, 5))
arr[tuple(verts.T)] = 1
print(arr)
```

output

```
[[1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```